# Post mark files as rename in git

Tags: git

We have renamed and changed some files in git and now git is displaying it as removed and added.

Is it possible to mark a file after a commit as rename in for example a rebase operation?

Would be nice to correct our history. Force push allowed ;)

Comment: Internally, Git doesn't track renames. It is always a "remove 200 lines here, add 200 lines there". It's only the output that recognises the rename and may show it to you.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to split up that commit that changed *and* renamed/moved the files to only do one of the two, ie. split the commit into one commit doing the rename/move, and another that changes their contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to mark a file as renamed/moved after the fact because there is no way to actually mark a file as renamed/moved in git at all, ever.

Internally in the repository, renames or moves are not tracked at all.

Instead, the *tooling* on top of the git repository, ie. the git executable and all its sibling executables, is doing this heavy lifting.

In particular, when a file has been added, some of the commands of git will look at the rest of the commit to see if it can locate the source of that file, such as another file that was deleted. Git will even try to match files that aren't identical in contents but it has to stop somewhere.

Which means that the changes you did to the files in the same commit are too extensive for this "look for similar files" algorithm to consider it a candidate for such a move/rename log output.

So basically your only option is to go back and redo that commit, by splitting it up into two (or more) distinct commits where you either move/rename the files or change them, but not both in the same commit.

So for instance, if your commit history looks like this:

```
Commit #1: Introduce some files
Commit #2: Move and change said files
Commit #3: Further change the moved files
```

you would split it up into this:

```
Commit #1: Introduce some files
Commit #2: Move files
Commit #3: Change said files
Commit #4: Further change the moved files
```

This should make the git tools able to see the renames/moves properly.

You could also try to split it up by reducing the amount of changes you did to the files but then you're just fighting thresholds. Better to reduce the chance of a mismatch to 0 by just doing a move/rename **or** a change, but not both, in the same commit.